# Is this sketch from Leonardo Da Vinci or his pupil Salai?

Tags: leonardo-da-vinci

Please excuse me if this question appears to be extremely inappropriate but it just looks quite strange to me... Recently I came across this sketch that is claimed to be from Leonardo Da Vinci or his pupil Salai (source of picture: https://dangerousminds.net/comments/an_x-rated_doodle_from_the_notebooks_of_leonardo_da_vinci):

[image]

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sala%C3%AC)

> A folio by Leonardo includes a page of drawings by a hand other than Leonardo's, one of which is a crudely drawn sketch depicting an anus, identified as "Salaì's bum", pursued by penises on legs.

But there is a note in the same Wikipedia page that says:

> The page on which this sketch appears is the same page that contains the depiction of a bicycle. Neither drawing is by Leonardo, and the page was not seen until a restoration of the volume in the 1960s, in the process of which, several pages went missing and were later returned. It has been suggested that the drawings are by a pupil of Leonardo's but this is debated.

So, it's quite puzzling that this sketch is really from Leonardo Da Vinci or at least from his pupil Salai or it's just fake. The thing that is suspicious is that the sketch looks like a sketch of some naughty high school teenagers and it's far from Leonardo Da Vinci's style. The other thing that makes me more suspicious is that bold black drawing on the second penis, which I'm not sure what that is... It's claimed the text on the right circle is "Salai" but at least I can't read it properly... I really appreciate it if someone explains this sketch is real or fake?

Comment: Of course it is fake. The person who drew it had no artistic talent at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane Any evidence why it’s fake? It seems Da Vinci or his pulis have a long story of inappropriate sketches... Search for “The Angel Incarnate”, which makes me wondering if this sketch comes truely from Da Vinci’s school.

Comment: Da Vinci and his pupils may have drawn "inappropriate" subject matter, but not so crude as the style of this drawing. Many of the straight lines appear to have been drawn with a ruler, with an inconsistent weight on the pen, whereas “The Angel Incarnate” has a proficient style.